# Local network multiplayer game with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, multiplayer, photon

I followed a tutorial link to create a multiplayer first person shooter game using Unity 3D. It uses Photon Unity Networking plugin. The games works fine. But the problem is it uses the Photon cloud. I want to convert this to an offline multiplayer game. Then I can use my LAN network or local Wi-Fi router to transfer game data. I need something like Call of Duty multiplayer. Is it possible to do it with Photon Unity Networking. If possible how to do that? What should I change in my code? Can you please suggest any tutorials on offline multiplayer game designing using Unity 3D. As I am quite new to programming please give me a detailed answer.

Multiplayer first person shooter tutorial link:
[link](http://quill18.com/unity_tutorials/MultiFPS/)

Comment: "how to do" is too broad a question, it cannot be answered within readonable scope. We can't tell you how to change your code if you don't post that code in the first place. Asking for offsite resources is offtopic.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have given the link which has the entire source code.

Comment: yeah, but code needs to go inside the question itself and narrowed down to what is needed for context. Links break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Photon Server Settings set the hosting mode to offline and try this code.

```
void Start () {

        Connect ();
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom("room1");
        //Create your player
    }

void Connect(){
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("your settings");
    }
```